# Not able to read files in Kaggle when running in background notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kaggle

I have saved some files in /kaggle/working/ directory and I can use them when I run the notebook in a client session. For instance running a cell  with this code

```
print('READ DIRECTORIES AND PRINT FILES LIST\n')

import os
for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk('/kaggle/'):
    for filename in filenames:
        print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
```

gives this output

```
READ DIRECTORIES AND PRINT FILES LIST

/kaggle/lib/kaggle/gcp.py
/kaggle/working/state.db
/kaggle/working/ANN SPY_30min - P_ITM - L 128-32-1 - DO 0995 - BS 512 - OPTIONS MODEL.h5
/kaggle/working/SPY_30min_final_df_fildered_40_DTE_51.csv
/kaggle/working/Test 2.csv
/kaggle/working/test.csv
```

But when I run the notebook in the background that files are not found and the notebook crashes when it tries to load one of them. The same above cell code gives as output the following

```
25.1s   24  READ DIRECTORIES AND PRINT FILES LIST
25.1s   25  
25.1s   26  /kaggle/src/script.ipynb
25.1s   27  /kaggle/lib/kaggle/gcp.py
25.1s   28  /kaggle/working/__notebook__.ipynb
```

How can i find the files I need when running in the background?

It is true also the opposite: files saved in the background running are not present in the client session and lost.